# rails i18n lazy lookup for module controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

If I have a controller with module `Api::V1` like this

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    print I18n.t('.messages')
    ...
  end
end
```

how can I write the localization file `en.yml` so that I can utilize lazy lookup feature inside my controller file?

I have tried

```
en:
  api/v1/users:
    index:
      messages: test message
```

But it was not working. Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this work? `print I18n.t('messages')`

Comment: @Sajin it's not working, the error message is `translation missing: en.messages`

Answer (score 2):

First use

```
en:
  api:
    users:
```

etc. as suggested by @sajin.

Then use `print t('.messages')` instead of `print I18n.t('.messages')` without the `I18n` to use the controllers implementation of translate instead of the general one from I18n.

Comment: just a note for those who are using an API-only app (controllers inheriting from `ActionController::API`), you must `include AbstractController::Translation` in your controller in order to be able to call `t` method directly and make the lookup mechanism to work as expected. It's not included by default.

Comment: I had a base class inheriting from ActionController::API so `include AbstractController::Translation` including this in my base API class worked for me and also structure as written by @sajin helped. You need to write all the folders' names until your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this. But can you try

```
en:
  api:
    v1:
      users:
        index:
          messages: test message
```

Comment: it was not working, I've got the `translation missing: en.messages` error again. And I have tried both `I18n.t('messages')` and `I18n.t('.messages')`, the result were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this reusing yaml translation block:

```
pt-BR:
  lazy: &lazy
    destroy:
      success: 'Competição removida com sucesso!'
    create:
      success: 'Competição foi criada com sucesso!'
    update:
      success: 'Competição foi alterada com sucesso!'
  swimming_competitions: 
    <<: *lazy
  admin:
    swimming_competitions:
      <<: *lazy
```